# java.lang.StackOverflowError when using tycho-surefire-plugin

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

I am trying to use `tycho-surefire-plugin` to run my JUnit Plugin Tests for an Eclipse RCP project.
This is the error I am getting when the tests run (`mvn clean verify`)

Here is how I configured tycho sure fire in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <application>org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication</application>
            <useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>
            <useUIThread>false</useUIThread>
            <product>org.eclipse.platform.ide</product>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I am using tycho 2.5

```
<properties>
      <tycho.version>2.5.0</tycho.version>
```

I initially was running tycho 1.4.0 but I was getting this error

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-10-22 23:16:31.983
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPlatformRunnable
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.UITestApplication.runApplication(UITestApplication.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.AbstractUITestApplication.run(AbstractUITestApplication.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.UITestApplication.start(UITestApplication.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
```

and seeing [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564890), I thought upgrading would fix it. While it did, I now get a StackOverFlow.

```
!SESSION 2021-10-22 23:05:12.961 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.9.1
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.uitest -testproperties C:\Users\user\git\project\core\net.project.tests\target\surefire.properties -testApplication org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -nouithread
Command-line arguments:  -data C:\Users\user\git\project\core\net.project.tests\target\work\data -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.uitest -testproperties C:\Users\user\git\project\core\net.project.tests\target\surefire.properties -testApplication org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -nouithread

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-10-22 23:05:15.071
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryAcquireShared(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:475)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1323)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleDatabase.readLock(ModuleDatabase.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleDatabase.getWiring(ModuleDatabase.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.getWiring(ModuleContainer.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleRevision.getWiring(ModuleRevision.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.getModuleClassLoader(EquinoxBundle.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.getApplication(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runt
    ..
```

Comment: It is recursively trying to start the same application - I'm not an expert in this but I would guess the `<application>` is wrong. Maybe just try the defaults?

Comment: For the record, I put this `application` because when I successfully run locally within Eclipse my tests, then I see in the console this `-application org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication`. I will try to remove/change the application.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I removed the `<application>` tag and it works now. Is there a way I can mark your comment as the "solution" ?

Comment: No, you can't accept a comment, don't worry about it. I don't feel I am expert enough in this to really write a proper answer.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks again!